# Как отправить массив в параметры POST запроса

Tags: java, массивы, http, post

Как в Java передать в параметры POST-запроса массив в форме application / x-www-form-urlencoded? Как строка должна выглядеть. Заранее большое спасибо) (я только новичок)

Comment: а что попробовали сами сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: request.setAttribute("array", array);